# Getting "Internal Server Error" while removing index.php from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to remove the index.php part from the url.
Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /faraztest

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I have also changed the config.php file, but still it says "Internal Server Error" when i put the url removing after removing "/index.php/". Please help.

Comment: does it stays when you just type url without `/index.php` in browser?

Comment: no, when i put the stated code in .htaccess file, i doesnt even respond to localhost/project/ and gives this error

Comment: try `[R=301,L]` enstead of `[L]` in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got this one done!

My **config.php**

```
$config['base_url']  = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

**.htaccess** resides in **/faraztest/.htacces**

My **.htaccess** file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /faraztest
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /faraztest/index.php
</IfModule>
```

And BANG! it worked!

2 things I was doing wrong was that I wasn't including

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
</IfModule>
```

and also in `ErrorDocument 404 /faraztest/index.php` I wasn't giving the correct file destination.

Answer (score 0):

Settings below always worked for me. If not working, check your `Network` tab in your browser to see what's going on.

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.example.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|web|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me, it looks like you didn't have your mod_rewrite module turned on, so go ahead, in your Apache settings turn on mod_rewrite module, restart your server and that's it.